# Redis client times out when connecting

Tags: ruby, redis, docker, amazon-elasticache

I have a Redis cluster running on ElastiCache.

Multiple processes connect to the Redis cluster. Each process lives within a Docker container. The processes are not all the same -- I have a `web` process, a `worker` process, etc.

After a few days of operating normally, some of my `web` processes begin to time out when connecting to Redis. When I `ssh` into an affected `web` container and try to reach the cluster via `redis-cli`, my connection to the cluster times out. This tells me that the issue affects the entire container, and not just the `web` process.

When I use `redis-cli` from any other container, I connect without problems.

My `web` processes create new connections as needed, and close old connections when they're idle for a long time. My guess is that any given Docker container can open a certain number of connections before reaching some kind of limit. After a few days, my `web` containers reach that limit.

Any idea how to go about fixing this?

--

One more detail: for some reason, resetting my Redis cluster fixes the issue across all `web` containers. Maybe the Redis server imposes a limit on how many connections can be opened from a given IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josiah and I had a long discussion [on the Redis Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/lDrmShyanT8) which helped solve my issue; hopefully the discussion can help someone else in the future.