# docker run long time make cache connection timedout

Tags: caching, docker, redis, docker-compose

I built my app with docker-compose , one container is database use mariadb image ,one php to run Laravel (I installed php-memcached or php-redis extension for my app), one cache container built on redis  docker image .
at first everything goes on well , but after running 2 or 3 days , I got  the php exception : Connection timed out [tcp://redis:6379];
I monitor the cpu and memory and network use zabbix installed by myself on host server , but I got these error :

monitor CPU

[image: monitor CPU]

monitor memory

[image: monitor memory]

I changed cache container to memcached and 2 or 3 days same thing happen,
the only way I found to solve this problem  is to restart system , and it can run another 2 or 3 days before getting the same error. you know it's not possible to restart system on production, so any one can suggest me where to solve the problem other than restarting system ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing problem with redis docker container. This type of error comes when memory is exhausted. You need to set max memory parameter of redis server.

Advice: Please try to use another image of redis.

Comment: thanks , just as I written in question , I've changed redis container to memcached and after 2 or 3 days I faced the same problem , I set memcached memory to 2G and it only cost about 1.4G , about 600M idle.

Comment: Please check this thread. [Redis client times out when connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167929/redis-client-times-out-when-connecting)

Comment: ok,thanks , I'll try to do what that thread told to find out the problem ~ after that I'll reply

Comment: I watched the memory usage ,its normal , and still same question , the only solution is to reboot the system...